# Replacement for struct in Kotlin and how to store the data in the run time

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I have to store and update the below variables in Kotlin

```
string name;
Array of Class Objects(5)
Array of Int(5)
```

```
C++ format:
struct subject
{
  string name;
  Array of Class Objects(5)
  Array of Int(5)
};

vector<subject> sub;
```

In other programming languages C/C++ for ex, we use struct and put everything above in that.

**Questions:**

1. How to store and update above values with mixture of different types like Array, string, etc., in Kotlin?
2. Arrays will not get updated in one stretch. Ex: When someone calls AIDL interface with **name**, I create instance of class and stored the object in **array of class obj(0)** and **integer array(0)** as well updated with some value.
   When the same AIDL interface is called with same name again, second instance of class will be created and store in **array of class obj(1)**and **integer array(1)** as well updated. As **name** is same, there is no need to update it again.
   How to check the name and update the other arrays in the run time?
3. An additional use case, I need to make vector of that struct(according to C++). How I can achieve this in Kotlin?

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question, could you please give a little bit more details?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I update the query again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `struct` you would use a `class` in Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html. There are several differences between the two that are relevant:

1. The declaration and class members and there implementation are done in the same place.
2. The constructor declaration is built into the class declaration.
3. Kotlin leans towards immutability. While you can reassign fields more often you will see `val` (like `const`) and immutable collections.

With that said, you would do something like this to implement your struct in Kotlin. The following isn't a literal 1 for 1 translation, but rather how you might solve your problem with idiomatic Kotlin:

```
class Subject(val name: String) {
  val objects = mutableListOf<NameOfThatClass>()
  val numbers = mutableListOf<Int>()
}
```

What's going on in that code snippet is that we are declaring a class `Subject`. It has a constructor that takes one argument called `name` of type `String`. The `val` keyword means that the argument will also be kept as a member variable, and that member variable cannot be reassigned. Next, in the class body, we declare and assign two more member variables. `objects` and `numbers` will also not be reassignable because of the `val` keyword, but instead of receiving a constructor argument as a value they receive the result of calling `mutableListOf()`, which creates more or less the equivalent of a `vector`. We could also use `arrayOfNulls(5)` and `arrayOfInt(5)`, but unless you very specifically need fixed-sized arrays it's easier and more common to use lists in Kotlin.

You would then use it like so:

```
val myName = "foo"
val myFirstObject = ...
val myFirstNumber = 1

val mySubject = Subject(myName)
mySubject.objects += myFirstObject
mySubject.numbers += myFirstNumber
```

The `+=` you see there isn't an actual reassignment, but an operator overload that acts as Kotlin's equivalent of `std::vector`'s `push_back()`: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-write.html#adding-elements.

Finally, as mentioned above, Kotlin's lists are what you would normally use in place of `vector`. However, it sounds like you want to be able to look up a specific entry by name, which is more efficient to do with a map https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/. You could do something like this:

```
val myMap = mutableMapOf<String, Subject>()
// add to the map like this
myMap[name] = Subject(name)
// get from the map like this (returns null if not in the map)
val mySubject = myMap[name]
// check if the subject is already in the map like this
myMap.containsKey(name)
```

Then, if you need to iterate over all the `Subject`s like you would with a `vector`, you can use `myMap.values` to get just the `Subject`s.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you very much. Cant we use data class instead of normal class in Kotlin?